# Automatically modifying related table based on entries

Tags: excel

I have a data set of employee's sales over a given period and a blank/custom column to be used for any adjustments needing to be added by Accounting like such:

[image: Data Set]

I would like to have another table whose rows are added anytime the Adjustment column is modified. It would look like this, but with the actual values for the Adjustments column:

[image]

The reason for my trying to accomplish this is due to the Data Set is coming directly from a localized Database and loses any adjustments entered in this row when the data is refreshed. There may be a simpler way to accomplish this just using the currently established connection to the database but I'm at a loss.